# How to change user config in docker tomcat 8?

Tags: java, tomcat, docker

Using docker quick start terminal I have started a tomcat container and it is running and i can able to open the tomcat homepage. But i can't able to open the manager app by using default username:"admin" password:"admin". How can i update the config of tomcat??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the doc https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/:
The configuration files are available in /usr/local/tomcat/conf/. By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required to operate the "/manager/html" web application. If you wish to use this app, you must define such a user in tomcat-users.xml.

If you want, you can replace this folder from your host with a volume in your run (`docker run [...] -v /your/conf/:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/ [...]`)

Comment: thanks @kilian its working for me now.. I created a new tomcat-users file in my host and copied it to the docker using `docker cp `.

Answer (score 0):

In your catalina base directory you need to include something like:

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager"/>
```

at file

```
"\CATALINA_BASE\conf\tomcat-users.xml"
```

For Manager Apps : GUI access

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
```